# Confusion in "this" keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a code in javascript

```
var x=20;
var a={
  x:10,
  fun:(function(){
        console.log(this);
        function q(){
              console.log(this);
        }
        q();
  })
}
a.fun();
```

It gives me

```
Object {x: 10, fun: function}
Window {stop: function, open: function, alert: function, confirm: function, prompt: function…}.
```

But I don't understand why last "this" point to the window object.
Please help me out how "this" keyword is actually working.

Comment: `this` depends on how the function is called, not where it is defined. See [Understanding the “this” keyword in JavaScript](https://toddmotto.com/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript/)

Comment: First gives you object because you are calling it as `a.` so the context is set to `a`. But in `q`, you are directly calling it and hence it will be set to default value of this (`window` in non-strict mode and `undefined` in strict mode)

Comment: @Rajesh So, what can I do so that last "this" point to the object a.

Comment: Inside `fun`, create a variable `var self = this;` and use it instead of this. If you still wish to use `this`, you can look into `.bind`, but I suggest using `self` instead

Comment: @Rajesh Thank you so much